# To extract numbers after a particular string

Tags: python-3.7

I want to extract a number that follows a specific string ':' and write a code that adds that number. I think.. can split it by space and extract it from it... Well, it doesn't work.

1.(12321 6,80.0:3 210.1:3!!!73 540.2:1++ 96.3:3!<<<<%% 689.4:3 24.5:4)

I want to extract the number 3 3 1 3 3 3 4 followed by ":" from this string and find out that the sum is 17.

```py
import re

var1 = '1.(12321 6,80.0:3 210.1:3!!!73 540.2:1++ 96.3:3!<<<<%% 689.4:3 24.5:4)'

item = var1.split(" ")
```

Comment: `sum([int(i) for i in re.findall('(?<=:)\\d+',var1)])`

Answer (score 0):

```
sum([int(i) for i in re.findall('(?<=:)\\d+',var1)])
 17
```

Comment: While this code may/may no solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations.